# What benefits does Windows Defender give me with a Microsoft Account?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-defender

Windows Defender wants me to sign in with a Microsoft Account for "enhanced security and other benefits".
However it doesn't explain what these benefits are. Also the website the program links to doesn't explain either as it redirects to the Microsoft Account web page.

What does Windows Defender give me for signing in with a Microsoft Account?

I'm using Windows 10 1909

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signing in will give you options to [store your Bitlocker recovery key in OneDrive](https://community.windows.com/en-us/stories/what-is-bitlocker-windows-10), protecting you from losing access to your system in the event that the drive key is damaged or otherwise lost.

You will also have access to remote-wipe and location tracking options via a Microsoft account.

Also, if you have Office 365 you might also have further improved [file recovery Ransomware protection via Onedrive](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-onedrive-blog/onedrive-files-restore-and-windows-defender-takes-ransomware/ba-p/188001), which will need you to have signed into your Microsoft account. At a minimum normal users will get some level of protection [WinHelpOnline: Windows Defender Yellow Exclamation Icon and “Set up OneDrive” Warning](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/set-up-onedrive-yellow-exclamation-defender-security-center/):

[image]

Other than recovery, account and data-loss prevention, you do not gain much else.  Windows Defender itself does not change how it performs.